# php glob does not contain some strings

Tags: php, glob

I have this glob

```
    $images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
```

it gets images in a images directory but some files contain the string "Insert" and "Swatch" and I dont want to return those files.

I've looked around for any example of how to exlude them from the glob but have had no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glob()` can't do that. You will need to traverse the result and exclude them yourself.

Comment: 8^ ( bummer; but that explains why I can't find an example

Comment: I'm finding solution for one hour. but, here it is... :-/